# How to add item for vertical to gridview

Tags: android

If we add item to `gridView` automatically added for horizontal,  how to add item vertically to `gridView` from top to bottom by column in Android.

Comment: try it with `android:orientation=vertical`...if its already vertical try changing it to `horizontal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView, in most cases uses a ListAdapter. You don't add items to a GridView, rather, you add them to the Adapter.

ListAdapters are not designed to give you a grid based layout. And so, it's not possible. I don't think GridView supports adding items at random indexes. At-least, the docs don't mention this.

Comment: i want few columns in gridview

Comment: @Jamshid You can set the number of colums of your GridView. But your question is not clear, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

**this is getView method of grid view adapter**

```
   @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ListView listView;
        if (view == null) {
            listView = (ListView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.product_list_row, null);
            listView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(COLUMN_WIDTH, COLUMN_WIDTH * max_size));
            listView.setDividerHeight(0);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int index, long l) {
                    if (getItem(i).size() > index) {
                        Product product = getItem(i).get(index);
                        if (product != null && !product.getStartPrice().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            ItemDetailDialog dialog = new ItemDetailDialog(mContext, getItem(i), index);
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            listView = (ListView) view;
        }

        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getItem(i));
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setCacheColorHint(0);

        listView.setId(i);

        listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
//                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return listView;
    }
```

**this is list view adapter**

```
/**
 * list view adapter
 */
private class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // list products
    private List<Product> products;

    //
    ProductRowView productRowView;

    //
    Product product;

    // constructor
    private ListViewAdapter(List<Product> products){
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Product getItem(int i) {
        if (products.size() <= i )
            return null;
        return products.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // any code
        return convertView;
    }
```